# Need Logic to filter data based on current time

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

i've this object as shown below,

```js
const user = {
  id: 3,
  name: "Clark Kent",
  mobileNumber: "1234567892",
  email: "example_user@gmail.com",
  role: "VAN_SALE",
  loc_update_permission: true,
  active_shifts: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Morning",
      startTime: "09:30:00",
      endTime: "05:30:00",
      coordinates: null,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Night",
      startTime: "06:30:00",
      endTime: "02:30:00",
      coordinates: null,
    },
  ],
};
```

what i'm trying to do is to get the currently active shift based on the current time.
like if the current time is between or equal to `09:30:00` and `05:30:00` then it should return `Morning` as currently active shift, vice versa (i'm storing the start and end time as `time` in my DB).

```js
function getCurrentActiveShift(user) {
  const currentTime = new Date();
  const currentHours = currentTime.getHours() * 60 + currentTime.getMinutes(); // Convert to minutes

  const shifts = user.active_shifts;

  console.log(currentTime);
  console.log(currentTime.toLocaleString());

  console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone);

  for (const shift of shifts) {
    const startParts = shift.startTime.split(":");
    const startHours = parseInt(startParts[0]) * 60 + parseInt(startParts[1]); // Convert to minutes

    const endParts = shift.endTime.split(":");
    const endHours = parseInt(endParts[0]) * 60 + parseInt(endParts[1]); // Convert to minutes

    // Handle shifts that span midnight
    if (endHours < startHours) {
      if (currentHours >= startHours || currentHours < endHours) {
        return shift;
      }
    } else {
      if (currentHours >= startHours && currentHours < endHours) {
        return shift;
      }
    }
  }

  return null; // No active shift found for the current time
}

const user = {
  id: 3,
  name: "Clark Kent",
  mobileNumber: "1234567892",
  email: "example_user@gmail.com",
  role: "VAN_SALE",
  loc_update_permission: true,
  active_shifts: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Morning",
      startTime: "09:30:00",
      endTime: "05:30:00",
      coordinates: null,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Night",
      startTime: "06:30:00",
      endTime: "02:30:00",
      coordinates: null,
    },
  ],
};

const currentShift = getCurrentActiveShift(user);
if (currentShift) {
  console.log(`Current active shift: ${currentShift.name}`);
} else {
  console.log("No active shift at the current time.");
}
```

this what i cam up with so far, but then for testing i added 10 hours to the current time like
`currentTime.setHours(currentTime.getHours() + 10);`, so then it should return `Night` as currently active shift, but it' still returning `Morning`.

can someone help me out here? do i need to change the way i store shift's time in db or something?

The main thing is there are people from 2 diff timezone using this logic, so if user from IST and AST timezones get this data, both of their current active shift should show morning if their current time is 9:00 AM.

Comment: `.getHours` gets the hour number (0-23). Instead, to add 10 hours, you'd add 10 hours worth of milliseconds, like `newTime = new Date(); newTime.setTime(currentTime.getTime() + 10 * 60 * 60 * 1000);`.

Comment: @Ouroborus i did try that, like
`const currentTime = new Date(); currentTime.setTime(currentTime.getTime() + 10 * 60 * 60 * 1000);`

but my code is still returning `Morning` as current shift when the `currentTime` is showing `10/12/2023, 9:46:35 PM`

Comment: Try using 24-hr times like 17:30 and 18:30

Comment: @James Oh yes, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Logically question is wrong, How we will know whether the time is in a 24-hour or 12-hour Format?**

I tried the below solution. I think it solves the problem.

```js
const user = {
  id: 3,
  name: "Clark Kent",
  mobileNumber: "1234567892",
  email: "example_user@gmail.com",
  role: "VAN_SALE",
  loc_update_permission: true,
  active_shifts: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Morning",
      startTime: "09:30:00",
      endTime: "05:30:00",
      coordinates: null,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Night",
      startTime: "06:30:00",
      endTime: "02:30:00",
      coordinates: null,
    },
  ],
};

function getCurrentActiveShift(user) {
  const currentTime = new Date();
  let hour = currentTime.getHours()
  if(hour>12) hour -= 12;
  const currentTimeStr = `${hour}${currentTime.getMinutes()}${currentTime.getSeconds()}`
  const shifts = user.active_shifts;
  for (const shift of shifts) {
    const {startTime, endTime} = shift;
    const [startTimeStr, endTimeStr] = [startTime.replaceAll(":", ""), endTime.replaceAll(":", "")]
    if(Math.min(startTimeStr, endTimeStr) <= currentTimeStr &&currentTimeStr<=  Math.max(startTimeStr, endTimeStr))
    return shift.name
    
  }
  return 'No Active shift'; // No active shift found for the current time
}

console.log(`Current active shift: ${getCurrentActiveShift(user)}`);
```

Comment: I ran the code, but it didn't behave as expected. It's currently 1:46 PM, and the code didn't recognize the morning shift as the active shift, even though it should have.

To resolve this, I used 24-hour time format, and it worked perfectly. Changing "5:30:00" to "17:30:00" did the trick on my code above.